# Is it possible to load a JS library to DocumentDB?

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I like to use complex functions in DocumentDB, inside a SP.
Can I load a JS library to be called from the SP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library I created called [documentdb-utils](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#support-for-require-in-server-side-scripts) has limited support for including libraries in your sprocs using `require(...)`. Note, it doesn't load them into DocumentDB independently to be called from another sproc, it simply inlines them in each sproc that needs it. It's surprising how big a library you can fit but it is not unlimited. You'll have multiple copies of some libraries on the server, one in each sproc that needs it but that doesn't seem to be a problem and I reload the sprocs every time I startup so I don't have a version control issue. There is only one version of each npm module in my project so the same one gets loaded regardless of how many sprocs it's `required` from.

You can use many npm modules with this functionality but not all. For instance, I couldn't get lowdash to work, so I had to settle for underscore. I have included [examples](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#using-asyncjs-and-underscorejs-inside-of-sprocs) of how to load underscore and async.js in the library. Here is the [test for loading and executing async.js](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/test-live/asyncInSprocTest.coffee). Here is the [test for loading underscore](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/test-live/underscoreTest.coffee).

Note, I'm using CoffeeScript to create the library. The tests and most of the examples are in CoffeeScript, but I have a few examples in JavaScript. Not to worry though because you can easily compile CoffeeScript to JavaScript. There is a lot of help on the web automating this.